# Add Angular.js to SharePoint when .json files are blocked

Tags: sharepoint-server, json, angularjs

The boss wants `AngularJS`, and the SharePoint Farm Nannies won't remove the restriction that prevents uploading .json files.

There appears to be a `manifest.json` in every folder, and then an errors and a `version.json` in the root.

Can AngularJS operate properly without these?
or
Do I need to do some heroic effort to include them, like:

1. Change the extension to .jsn, upload, then find and replace everywhere in the library that refers to the .json to be .jsn ??
   or
2. Something you suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: Solutions and explanations at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114540/why-is-upload-of-json-files-prohibited

Comment: Non-answer as I didn't build this library... it's AngularJS (This is why I've suggested my #1 above.) But, before I make such a heroic effort to modify such a library, I want some ideas from those familiar with it.